# Cannot manage to use innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm new to Stack Overflow and also in JavaScript. So, first of all, hello to everyone and thanks in advance for your help.

I'm using Incomedia Website X5 Evolution to create a website. On one of the page, I want to populate a table with data from a server. So, I've created a table and insert in each cell this HTML code:

```
<!--#0000,0000-->
```

Values are representing the row and the column. I managed to write a javascript to change the value of each cell. But when I want to replace the content of the HTML pahe using innerHTML, it does not work. Nevertheless, everything seems correct as the old and the new html content is the same. Even if I just use again the original variable, it still doesn't work.

Could you tell me where is the problem please ?

Here the javascript code:

```
<script>

var i;
var div = document.getElementById('imTableObject_1');
div = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var htmlContent = div[0].innerHTML;
var newHtmlContent = div[0].innerHTML;
var test = div[0].innerHTML;
var row,col;

//I can't understand why the scrip stop running at this line. I didn't change anything...
div[0].innerHTML = newHtmlContent ;

for (i=htmlContent.length - 5; i > -1; i--) {

if(htmlContent.charAt(i)=='#') {

    //alert(i);
    //alert(htmlContent.substring(i+6,i+10));
    row = parseInt(htmlContent.substring(i+1,i+5));     
    col = parseInt(htmlContent.substring(i+6,i+10));

    newHtmlContent = insertText(row,col,newHtmlContent,i);
};
};

alert(div[0].innerHTML);
alert(newHtmlContent );

//This does not work
div[0].innerHTML = newHtmlContent ;

alert("Done !");



function insertText (row, col, text, index) {

var length;
var newText;

length = getTextLength (text,index + 13);

//alert(htmlContent.substring(index+13,index+13+length));

newText = text.substring(0,index+13);
newText += "Titi too !";
newText += text.substring(index+13+length,text.length);

//alert(newText);

return newText ;

}

function getTextLength (text,startIndex) {

var i = 0;

for(i = startIndex ; i < text.length ; i++) {

    //alert(text.substring(i,i+7));

    if(text.substring(i,i+7) == "</span>") {

        return i - startIndex ;
    };
};

return -1;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure `if(htmlContent.charAt(i)=='#') {` is ever true? And that the surrounding `for` loop runs correctly?

Comment: what do you get from the alerts?

Comment: also, could you include the HTML as well? it might help

Answer (score 0):

You set:

```
var newHtmlContent = div[0].innerHTML;
```

And then:

```
div[0].innerHTML = newHtmlContent ;
```

You're setting its content to what its content already was. Hence, no change occurs.

Comment: At first, yes, but later, they do `newHtmlContent = insertText(row,col,newHtmlContent,i);` and then call `div[0].innerHTML = newHtmlContent ;` again

Answer (score 0):

Change the 3rd row to

```
div = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
```

to look for `<td>` tags instead of `<table>` tags. `<table>`s can't directly store text data so I guess their `innerHTML` doesn't work as expected either.

I managed to get it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/mgabor/ZMaW6/1/